# Unable to execute mojo: Unable to find artifact - Alfresco SDK 3.0

Tags: sdk, alfresco, alfresco-maven

I am trying to setup Dev environment for Alfresco Community using Alfresco SDK 3.0.

I have created an all-in-one project, ran the run.bat as mentioned in the documentation and everything ran as expected.

Now, my actual project uses a similar parent pom.xml; only changes being as follows.

instead of 
`<artifactId>alfresco</artifactId>`
we have it as 
`<artifactId>cust-acs</artifactId>`

Under `<platformModules>` stanza, instead of

```
<moduleDependency>
<groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
<artifactId>alfresco-platform-jar</artifactId>
<version>${project.version}</version>
</moduleDependency>
```

it is

```
<moduleDependency>
       <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
       <artifactId>cust-acs-platform-jar</artifactId>
       <version>${project.version}</version>
</moduleDependency>
```

and under `<shareModules>` stanza, instead of

```
<moduleDependency>
     <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
     <artifactId>alfresco-share-jar</artifactId>
     <version>${project.version}</version>
 </moduleDependency>
```

it is

```
<shareModules>
   <moduleDependency>
   <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
   <artifactId>cust-acs-share-jar</artifactId>
   <version>${project.version}</version>
   </moduleDependency>
</shareModules>
```

Also, I included `<server>` stanza in maven settings.xml with relevant credentials.

But, when I run this parent pom.xml, I get this error

```
Failed to execute goal org.alfresco.maven.plugin:alfresco-maven-plugin:3.0.1:run (default-cli) on project cust-acs: Unable to execute mojo: Unable to find artifact. Could not find artifact com.<groudID>:cust-acs-platform-jar:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in alfresco-public (https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public)
```

What am I missing here? How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a firewall issue, please configure your proxy related settings in the maven `settings.xml` under your .m2 folder, restart your cmd and try again. FYI the `artifact-id` is something you provide for your specific project when setting up sdk3 with command-line. the module dependencies simply refer to your platform and share jars under the AIO project.

Comment: Okay. I understand that I need to add a `<proxy>` stanza here. But, what would the credentials be; I mean I am merely connected to a broadband service.

Comment: I have checked for proxy settings and have found that there is no proxy used. Now, how do I proceed? Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is complaining that it cannot find the artifact `cust-acs-platform-jar`. Did you manually add this module to your maven project? Which goal did you try to run?

I suggest trying to do a full `mvn clean install`, verify that the artifact `cust-acs-platform-jar` is in fact part of your build.

Otherwise, we'd need more info on the Maven project, like the full `pom.xml`.